# Range Bars & Pivot Point Indicator to work simultaneously in Tradingview/PineScript

Tags: pine-script

In Tradingview, I'm trying to get the Pivot Point Indicator (Daily, Weekly, Monthly, Yearly) to run off time based data - 5 min, 15min, etc.), while the price bars I'd like to see are Range Bars. I believe that using the following function, it is possible to get them to work simultaneously.

```
***sec1 = security(syminfo.prefix+":"+syminfo.ticker, "15", close, lookahead=true)***
```

However, something is missing from this function, and it does not work properly.

Can someone guide on how to fix this?

Many thanks in advance.
Ayush

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this example ca n help

```
//@version=4
study("My Script")
ppH = security(syminfo.tickerid, "15", pivothigh(high, 5, 5), lookahead=true)
plot(ppH)
```